# as.h2o skips part of my original (large) R dataframe without error

Tags: r, h2o

I am trying to convert larger data.frames consisting of round about 70 numerical columns and one character column to h2o objects.
There is no error message but it only converts a fraction of the data frame and skips the rest (i.e. the number of rows of the resulting h2o object is much lower than the one of the original data frame)
Has anybody an advice?

Here an example (I build an example data frame similar to the one I am trying to analyze in my study.)

```
nameDF <- c(paste("O",letters, sep="_"),  paste("T",letters, sep="_"),
   paste("TR",letters, sep="_"))
DF <- matrix( data=numeric(length(nameDF)*1000000), nrow=1000000)
colnames(DF) <- nameDF
DF <- as.data.frame(DF)
DF$char <- rep("bla", 1000000)
DFh2o <- as.h2o(DF)
dim(DFh2o)
dim(DF)
```

Comment: Your code is broken up - does the last line go with the last `dim` command? Also, what is the _fraction_ it converts, and how does that error show up in your analysis?

Comment: Sorry I corrected the code. There is no error message. The code runs perfectly on one machine but it fails on another similar one (same hardware, windows version, and same R library i.e. same packages over a network). It converts 10 to 20% of the raws and leaves the last few fields in the matrix with 'NAs' even though there are no NA in the original matrix.

Comment: What are the versions of Java, h2o and R you're using? What's the specification of the machines you're running this code on?

Comment: 1) Jave Version 7 Update 71. On the other machines (the code is running properly on), I have Version 7 Update 80. 2) Windows 7 3) Intel Core i7 - 2600 CPU, 3.4 GHz with 16 GB RAM. 4) I am using R Open 3.3.1 (the same version as on the other machines).  Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the relatively recent H2O 3.10.4.8, ran your code sample, and the behavior of the two dims looks like the correct behavior to me.

```
> library(h2o)
> h2o.init()

H2O is not running yet, starting it now...

Note:  In case of errors look at the following log files:
    /var/folders/tt/g5d7cr8d3fg84jmb5jr9dlrc0000gn/T//RtmpCXcmAu/h2o_tomk_started_from_r.out
    /var/folders/tt/g5d7cr8d3fg84jmb5jr9dlrc0000gn/T//RtmpCXcmAu/h2o_tomk_started_from_r.err

java version "1.8.0_112"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b16, mixed mode)

Starting H2O JVM and connecting: .. Connection successful!

R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
    H2O cluster uptime:         2 seconds 605 milliseconds 
    H2O cluster version:        3.10.4.8 
    H2O cluster version age:    1 month and 15 days  
    H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_tomk_jgy651 
    H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
    H2O cluster total memory:   3.56 GB 
    H2O cluster total cores:    8 
    H2O cluster allowed cores:  2 
    H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
    H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
    H2O Connection port:        54321 
    H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
    H2O Internal Security:      FALSE 
    R Version:                  R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) 

Note:  As started, H2O is limited to the CRAN default of 2 CPUs.
       Shut down and restart H2O as shown below to use all your CPUs.
           > h2o.shutdown()
           > h2o.init(nthreads = -1)

> nameDF <- c(paste("O",letters, sep="_"),  paste("T",letters, sep="_"),
+ paste("TR",letters, sep="_"))
> DF <- matrix( data=numeric(length(nameDF)*1000000), nrow=1000000)
> colnames(DF) <- nameDF
> DF <- as.data.frame(DF)
> DF$char <- rep("bla", 1000000)
> View(DF)
> DFh2o <- as.h2o(DF)
  |=====================================================================================================================| 100%
> dim(DFh2o)
[1] 1000000      79
> dim(DF)
[1] 1000000      79
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. I also get the correct result on all but on one machine I ran the code on. The error seems to be hardware or version specific. I thought, that maybe somebody has a suspicion regarding the cause of that issue.

Answer (score 0):

For the case that somebody has the same issue, I post the simple solution to my problem: The machine I was running the code on only had little space left on the disk the h2o objects were saved to. The solution is simple, however h2o doesn't throw an error in its log files so one doesn't see the problem right away.... best regards!